# Is there a term for a set of eigenvalues not containing any roots of unity except 1?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots-of-unity, complex-dynamics

Is there a term describing a matrix $A \in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ whose eigenvalues are all either $1$ or not a root of unity?

Is there a term for a holomorphic selfmap $F$ of $\mathbb C^n$ fixing $0 \in \mathbb C^n$ whose linear part $dF_0$ satisfies the same property?

Background: In the dynamics of holomorphic selfmaps $F$ of $\mathbb C^n$ fixing $0 \in \mathbb C^n$, many results are stated only for maps of the above form (silently justified in that you can always pass to an iterate $F^k$ with that property).